# Finding the initial permutation

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms, permutations

Assume a permutation P[1], P[2], ..., P[n].

Now we  have made N permutations Q[1], Q[2], ..., Q[N],

**Q[i] is permutation P without element i (we subtract 1 from all elements bigger than i)**.

For example If permutation was [8 1 2 3 4 5 6 7] then without 5 it becomes [7 1 2 3 4 5 6].

Now suppose we had made a random shuffle of Q and we need to find initial permutation P.

Example : Let we have 3 elements and here is the shuffled Q :

```
1 2
1 2
1 2
```

Then obviously the initial permutation is simply [1 2 3] as it satisfy all the three conditions.

Now I want to have an algorithm or way to find out initial permutation if am given this Q.

NOTE : Algorithm can be exponential as I want to evaluate for N at max 50

Comment: Is there a source for this problem?

Comment: @Irvan Actually It was just for a given array.I was thinking to generalise it.

Comment: I meant, did you come up with this problem yourself, or did you find this problem elsewhere?

Comment: @Irvan Myself..Not any such source